# Find and delete all occurrences of a string that starts with x

Tags: c#, regex, xml, xmldiff

I'm parsing an XML file, to compare it to another XML file. XML Diff works nicely, but we have found there are a lot of junk tags that exist in one file, not in the other, that have no bearing on our results, but clutter up the report. I have loaded the XML file into memory to do some other things to it, and I'm wondering if there is an easy way at the same time to go through that file, and remove all tags that start with, as an example color=. The value of  color is all over the map, so not easy to grab them all remove them.

Doesn't seem to be any way in XML Diff to specify, "ignore these tags".

I could roll through the file, find each instance, find the end of it, delete it out, but I'm hoping there will be something simpler. If not, oh well.

Edit: Here's a piece of the XML:

```
<numericValue color="-103" hidden="no" image="stuff.jpg" key="More stuff." needsQuestionFormatting="false" system="yes" systemEquivKey="Stuff." systemImage="yes">
    <numDef increment="1" maximum="180" minimum="30">
        <unit deprecated="no" key="BPM" system="yes" />
   </numDef>
</numericValue>
```

Comment: Select all nodes with XPath like `//*['contains(local-name(), "color")]` and delete them?

Comment: With what? Can you use xpath in a string replace in c#?

Comment: So you want to use string manipulation to edit XML - good luck. I can't stop you from doing so, but please consider other, more XML specific tools like XDocument/XmlDocument classes.

Comment: Not tied to anything. As I had already loaded it for other purposes, it would be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Linq to XML, you can load your XML into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // Load the XML from a string
```

Or

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName); // Load the XML from a file.
```

Then search for all elements with matching names and use [`System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove them all at once:

```
        string prefix = "L"; // Or whatever.

        // Use doc.Root.Descendants() instead of doc.Descendants() to avoid accidentally removing the root element.
        var elements = doc.Root.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        elements.Remove();
```

**Update**

In your XML, the `color="-103"` substring is an [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp) of an element, rather than an element itself.  To remove all such attributes, use the following method:

```
    public static void RemovedNamedAttributes(XElement root, string attributeLocalNamePrefix)
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        foreach (var node in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
            node.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == attributeLocalNamePrefix).Remove();
    }
```

Then call it like:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // Load the XML

        RemovedNamedAttributes(doc.Root, "color");
```

Comment: Nice. What is the format of that xml variable? I've just read the xml file as a file into memory.

Comment: It's a string variable.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to disappear. I run the code with the prefix set to "color", but when I write it out, the color elements are still there. It parses in just fine, so I'm assuming it's valid XML.

Comment: @CargoMeister - do you want to remove the `color="-103"` attribute, or the entire `numericValue` element?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it this morning.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Knew there had to be a good answer to this. Saved me a huge amount of time.